# How to get bytes from NSPasteboard

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

there's a binary file opened in `Hex Fiend`:

[Hex Fiend Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lfed.png)

I highlighted the first `288` bytes and copied with `CMD+C`

then I tried to retrieve it from code:

```
    NSPasteboard *pboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard;
    NSString *content = [pboard stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
    NSData *data1 = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
    NSData *data2 = [pboard dataForType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
```

`data1` and `data2` look something like:

```
{length = 435, bytes = 0x41c39a67 c28d3c18 c3847a1e c2bf5dc2 ... bac3884f 3274c3b8 }
```

I pasted the content with `CMD+V` into `Sublime Text` and `VS code`, they can both show it right:

[Sublime Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu0YX.png)

My question is: **how to get the exact 288 bytes back from NSPasteboard**

Thank you guys!

---

**Update**:

```
    NSPasteboard *pboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard;
    for (NSString *t in pboard.types) {
        NSLog(@"pboard type: %@, data length: %ld", t, [pboard dataForType:t].length);
    }
    NSLog(@"----");
    for (NSPasteboardItem *item in [pboard pasteboardItems]) {
        for (NSString *type in [item types]) {
            NSData *data = [item dataForType:type];
            NSLog(@"item type: %@, data length: %ld", type, data.length);
        }
    }
```

result:

```
2022-04-11 16:08:59.726507+0800 testapp[50006:2713553] pboard type: dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yuvwusmy1q2pyqzbhw7dfkf3he2p3nbvg82pwqvnhw6df, data length: 341
2022-04-11 16:08:59.726649+0800 testapp[50006:2713553] pboard type: HFPrivateByteArrayPboardType, data length: 341
2022-04-11 16:08:59.733329+0800 testapp[50006:2713553] pboard type: public.utf8-plain-text, data length: 435
2022-04-11 16:08:59.733525+0800 testapp[50006:2713553] pboard type: NSStringPboardType, data length: 435
2022-04-11 16:08:59.733581+0800 testapp[50006:2713553] ----
2022-04-11 16:08:59.733722+0800 testapp[50006:2713553] item type: dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yuvwusmy1q2pyqzbhw7dfkf3he2p3nbvg82pwqvnhw6df, data length: 341
2022-04-11 16:08:59.733806+0800 testapp[50006:2713553] item type: public.utf8-plain-text, data length: 435
```

I still cannot get the expected `288` bytes

---

**Update2**

Snapshot from `Clipboard Viewer` shows bytes for invisible characters are modified.

[HFPrivateByteArrayPboardType snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTkgr.png)

[invisible characters snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylrLM.png)

Yes, HexFiend is open sourced but the code is complicated for me :(
I have not yet figured out how to read from `HFPrivateByteArrayPboardType` plist.

Comment: `stringForType:` returns a string, `dataForType:` would return the data. Inspect the pasteboards `types` to see what is available. It is normal for data on the pasteboard to be available in various representations.

Comment: Is the issue reproducable with the Hex view and Source Code view of Xcode? Have you tried Clipboard Viewer, an Xcode Additional Tool? Hexfiend is open source, how is the data written to the pasteboard? Can Hexfiend paste? What gets pasted in TextEdit?

Comment: @Willeke sorry, I was wrong. After my double check, neither Sublime Text nor VS Code, can correctly get back the origin 288 bytes. They can only show 288 characters actually (435 bytes). My bad! It seems like it is not possible to pass binary data across apps via general string type clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I was wrong.

After my double check, neither `Sublime Text` nor `VS Code`, can correctly get back the origin 288 bytes. They can only show 288 converted characters actually (435 bytes). My bad!

It seems like it is not possible to safely pass binary data across different apps via general string type clipboard. (Please correct me if I'm wrong :) )